# Java, matrix overflow

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, int, overflow

It's not compiling for some reason. I'm new to java and I'm trying to learn this. I don't know what's wrong with this program. Can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

> Error communicate :
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>
> at Matrix.main(Matrix.java:17)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int w=3,k=2;
        int[][] x = {                           //Tworzy tablice 4x3 (3x2, bo a1=[0,0])
                {1,12,3},                       //x[0,0]=1  x[0,1]=12 x[0,2]= 3
                {45,4,1,0},                     //x[1,0]=45 x[1,1]=4  x[1,2]= 1  x[1,3]=0
                {2,3}                           //x[2,0]=2  x[2,1]=3
        };
        int[][] matX = new int[w][k];           //tab[w,k]
        
        for(int i=0 ; i<matX.length ; i++) {
            for(int j=0 ; j<matX[w].length ; j++) {
                matX[i][j] = data.nextInt();
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=0 ; i<matX.length ; i++) {
            for(int j=0 ; j<matX[w].length ; j++) {
                System.out.println(matX[i][j]);
                if(j==matX[w].length-1) {
                    System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
        }
        data.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Matrix is everywhere. It is all around us. Even now, in this very post. You can see it when you turn on your computer and log in to Stackoverflow. You can feel it when you go to school... when you go to do homework.... It is the world that has been pulled over your eyes to blind you from the truth. The truth that you are a slave, Setzo. Like everyone else you were born into bondage. Into a prison that you cannot taste or see or touch. A prison for your mind. THAT, is what's wrong with your program. That, and what rgettman posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a length `w` as an index into `matX`, which is itself an invalid index.  Change

```
j<matX[w].length
```

to:

```
j<matX[i].length
```

using the outer loop variable `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `matX[i]` and not `matX[w]` inside your loops, here some code to start with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix { public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int w=3,k=2;
    int[][] x = {                           //Tworzy tablice 4x3 (3x2, bo a1=[0,0])
            {1,12,3},                       //x[0,0]=1  x[0,1]=12 x[0,2]= 3
            {45,4,1,0},                     //x[1,0]=45 x[1,1]=4  x[1,2]= 1  x[1,3]=0
            {2,3}                           //x[2,0]=2  x[2,1]=3
    };
    int[][] matX = new int[w][k];           //tab[w,k]

    for(int i=0 ; i<matX.length ; i++) {
        for(int j=0 ; j<matX[i].length ; j++) {
            matX[i][j] = data.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<matX.length ; i++) {
        for(int j=0 ; j<matX[i].length ; j++) {
            System.out.println(matX[i][j]);
            if(j==matX[i].length-1) {
                System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
    }
    data.close();
}
```